# Связи между двумя dbGrid-ами - C#

Tags: c#, dbgrid

Имеется привязанная база данных *Access* cо связями.

Мне необходимо реализовать следущее: при нажатии на товар в первом *dbGrid*, что-бы во втором выделялась соответствующая характеристика этому товару.

Пробовал делать [так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y8c0cxey(v=vs.110).aspx),  но не получилось и код  не понятен мне.

Answer (score 0):

Создать вторую связанную таблицу с полем наименования товара и его характеристикой. Потом забрать с 1-го грида ID товара, с помощью запроса найти во второй таблице аналогичный ID  и вывести его характеристику(при нажатии клавиши, либо выборе в 1-м гриде).

Comment: в базе  данных  уже есть  вторая таблица с  ID характеристики.   проблема  в том что я не знаю   как написать сам запрос и куда.